# How to change Chart Js Treemap font Size

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, font-size, treemap

I am using the treemap from chartjs. I am having trouble making the font size bigger in the larger blocks and smaller in the small blocks. Here is my code:

```
const options = {
    legend: {
      show: true,
    },
    chart: {
      height: 350,
      type: "treemap",
      events: {
        dataPointSelection: treemapOnClick,
      },
      fontSize: "19px",
    },
    title: {
      text: "Title Here",
      align: "center",
    },

    dataLabels: {
      formatter: function (val, { seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w }) {
        let labelWords = val.split(" ");
        let labelElements = [];
        let currentLine = "";

        for (let i = 0; i < labelWords.length; i++) {
          let word = labelWords[i];
          if (currentLine.length + word.length > 30) {
            labelElements.push(currentLine);
            currentLine = "";
          }
          if (currentLine !== "") {
            currentLine += " ";
          }
          currentLine += word;
        }

        if (currentLine !== "") {
          labelElements.push(currentLine);
        }

        return labelElements;
      },
    },
  };
```

```
<Chart options={options} series={treemapList} type="treemap" height={350} className={classes.chartStyles} />
```

I tried adding the following, and a bunch of other stuff, but no luck:

```
      plugins: {
          legend: {
            labels: {
              // This more specific font property overrides the global property
              font: {
               size: 18,
          },
        },
      },
    },
```

Comment: I cannot recognize of Chart.js options. Can you provide the whole config?

Comment: `<Chart options={options} series={treemapList} type="treemap" height={350} className={classes.chartStyles} />`

Comment: Thank you but I meant the "options" content because what you published is not clear to me.

Comment: As @user2057925 already remarked, these are not chart.js options. Actually,  the options in your `const options` object are from apexcharts. So if you are indeed using chart.js, they have no effect, in javascript they are just ignored (with typescript you'll get type errors, but it would probably still compile).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. If I don't use the options to change the font of the labels, is there perhaps another way that I've missed?